# Google Chrome issue: No Form Submission with Code that Disables the Submit Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I want to disable the submit button once it has been clicked. This is my submit button code:

```
<button title="<?PHP echo getTranslatedString('LBL_SAVE_ALT'); ?>" accessKey="S" class="btn btn-primary" value="<?PHP echo getTranslatedString('LBL_SAVE_LAPTOP'); ?>" id="formSave" type="submit" name="button" onclick="return checkform();">
    Save detail
</button>
```

And this is the `onclick` function and code:

```
function checkform() {
    var incvfr=$("#invoice").val();
    var inseridf=$("#invserial").val();
    if (incvfr== 1) {
        if (inseridf=='') {
            alert("Please enter invoice number");
            return false;
        }
    }
    var name=$("#name").val();
    var mobile=$("#mobile").val();
    var email=$("#email").val();
    var switchs=$("#switch").val();
    var brand=$("#brand").val();
    var processor=$("#processor").val();
    var ram=$("#ram").val();
    var hdd=$("#hdd").val();
    var color=$("#color").val();
    var broken=$("#broken").val();
    var os=$("#os").val();
    var battery=$("#battery").val();
    var adapter=$("#adapter").val();
    var phycond=$("#phycond").val();
    var lpserial=$("#lpserial").val();
    var lpdoc=$("#lpdoc").val();
    var idproof=$("#idproof").val();
    if (name!='' && mobile!='' && email!='' && switchs!='' && brand!=''
            && processor!='' && ram!='' && hdd!='' && color!='' && broken!='' 
                && os!='' && battery!='' && adapter!='' && phycond!='' && lpserial!='' 
                    && lpdoc!='' && incvfr!='' && idproof!='') {
        var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i].disabled = true;
        }
        document.getElementById("idproof").disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i].disabled = false;
        }
        document.getElementById("idproof").disabled = false;
    }
    //document.getElementById("formSave").disabled = true;
}
```

When I submit the form in `Mozilla Firefox` it works, but it does not work in `Google Chrome` (it only disables the button; it does not send the form submit).

Comment: your code, as you posted it, does not disable the submit button - it disables something with th id `idproof` - no idea what that is. Do you get any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: No sir in firefox it disable button and submit form but same code not worked for crome

Comment: i solve my problem to use css to disable button

Comment: that solves the click problem, just make sure you also "blur" the button (as in opposite of focus, not the graphic effect) - because `SPACE` and `ENTER` on the keyboard **will** still trigger that button if it has focus!!